# Get birthday and location with login from ASP.Net Core Facebook authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, facebook-login, asp.net-core-identity

I have troubles using the default template that implements Facebook login (and other providers).
I can get logged to the app, however logged I would like to arrive on a register form, pre-filled with Facebook data (in order to complete the profile).
I don't have issue to get the default claims (email, names), however I can't add birthday or location.

My startup has the following lines:

```
fo.Scope.Add("public_profile");
fo.Scope.Add("email");
fo.Scope.Add("user_birthday");
fo.Scope.Add("user_location");
...
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(fo);
```

This works, but does not ask for these permissions during the login process.
And if I add

```
fo.Fields.Add("location"); or 
fo.Fields.Add("user_birthday");
```

The login process in the callback fails.

The external login call is the default one:

```
var redirectUrl = Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", Name, new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);
return Challenge(properties, provider);
```

And the callback is the following:

```
        var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (info == null)
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));

        // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login.
        var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(5, "User logged in with {Name} provider.", info.LoginProvider);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(SendCode), new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
        if (result.IsLockedOut)
            return View("Lockout");
        else
        {
            // If the user does not have an account, then ask the user to create an account.
            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
            ViewData["LoginProvider"] = info.LoginProvider;

            Console.WriteLine("Debug claims!");
            foreach (var c in info.Principal.Claims)
                Console.WriteLine("---> " + c.Subject + ":" + c.Value + "   " + c.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine("End Debug claims!");
```

I never got anything more than the default claims and got some exceptions like this when adding the Fields on startup

```
  An unhandled exception has occurred: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).
at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook.FacebookHandler.<CreateTicketAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.OAuthHandler`1.<HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
```

Any idea on how to do this? (not via the graph API, even if it is much easier)
I have been searching for hours and cannot find anything else than "email" issues.

The two issues are:
1. Why at login, the scopes set on startup are not required?
2. How to retreive the fields from Facebook? (birthday, gender, location)